# How to handle unique indexes with MySQL master master replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, unique-index

how do you handle UNIQUE indexes in a master-master active-active replication environment?

SQL schema example:

```
CALLS
  id INTEGER PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT
  caller_id INTEGER + INDEX
  start_date datetime
  end_date datetime
  ...

CALLERS
  id INTEGER PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT
  phone VARCHAR UNIQUE
  country_id CHAR(2)
  city_id INTEGER
  ...
```

In a heavy loaded (lot of inserts) environment, requests can be sent to both master (for perf, high availability, 0 downtime schema changes reasons).

if 2 CALLERS records are created at the same time (yes it can) on both masters:

- In a replication mode=row the replication breaks with a DUPLICATE event
- In a replication mode=row with a ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE the replication breaks too (since the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is not applied on the opposite master)
- In a replication mode=statement the replication breaks too
- In a replication mode=statement with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE the replication keep working... but we can have inconsistent records:

  if 2 CALLERS are created at the same time on both masters,

  - master1.CALLERS.id=1 masters1.CALLS.caller_id = 1
  - master2.CALLERS.id=2 master2.CALLS.caller_id = 2
  - on both master, once replicated, the replicated CALLS records will have a caller_id columns pointing on a non-existent records

What are the best solutions to handle this really simple case?

I thought to solutions like this, but they have big drawbacks

- don't use UNIQUE indexe in these cases  by merging CALLERS and CALLS table, but this is a huge functional loss... and keep using ROW based replication. but:

  - this is not applicable to all UNIQUE indexes cases!
- don't use AUTO_INCREMENT (don't let MySQL choose the id values), but:

  - how will you generate alternative unique values without SPOF and without performances degradations? (something that could fit in a 4 Bytes column)
  - have to change all the application (more than hundred tables in the real one)

Comment: you can set the AUTO_INCREMENT so that one Master create only even and the other odd Ids. So both Master can create Records at the same time without problems

Comment: This is absolutely not linked to the problems.... the problem is not with AUTO INC but with UNIQUE indexes

Comment: sorry - my mistake. Why you not use Galera Option. so the replication is synced. if you use MariaDB 10.1x you can handle both async and Galera replication

Comment: The inconsistency problem in mode=statement indicates that you are not using transactions. You are updating two tables at the same time (callers and calls) and because they are related they should be in the same transaction to avoid the inconsistencies.

Comment: 2 records can be in the same transactions, still doesn't solve the UNIQUE indexe hell

@BerndBuffen > it could be a possibility! the sync mode would prevent the creation at the same time of a unique key on both sides

Comment: Try Galera Gluster from MariaDB 10.1. it works for both async Replication and wsrep replication. There you can do it. If you create on each node the same key one of the nodes will inform you and rollback the trans action. so you can do it again. Here is a pdf (from 2013) but it work or read this: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/galera-cluster/

Answer (score 2):

Multi-master with standard replication does *not* improve write performance -- all writes must be applied to all Masters.

Multi-master with standard replication has a number of problems with `UNIQUE` and `PRIMARY` keys.  This is the main reason most people avoid *writing* to both Masters.

`AUTO_INCREMENT` problems can usually be prevented by using `auto_increment_increment` = the number of masters, and `auto_increment_offset` set to different values (1,2,..).  That is what Galera does under the covers.

`ROW` versus `STATEMENT` -- should not make any difference.

Galera has many advantages, especially if you have at least 3 nodes.  Especially since HA is a goal.

You have lots of `INSERTs`?  Are they single-row, or batched, or `LOAD DATA`?  Single-row is much slower (in any context) than either of the others.  In all contexts, you must check for errors.  In some cases you can get a "deadlock" and "rollback", necessitating replay of the transaction.

Beware of `IGNORE` option -- it can "burn" auto_increment ids.  [More discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/datawarehouse#batched_insert_statement).

See also [Techniques for really high speed ingestion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table).  Perhaps you can get adequate speed on a single machine.

Side note:  `country_id CHAR(2)` should be `CHARACTER SET ascii`; with `utf8` it would occupy 6 bytes always.